# Javascript code works different in different cases

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My script doesn't works when I use requirejs library to launch it.

It's a simple game. After I click "start" program draws squares and when a green square appear the user has to click it as quick as possible. Then on the screen shows result how quick he did it.

Under this link script working properly:
http://doomini2.linuxpl.info/correct/

When the script was loaded from normal js file everything was fine.
But when it's loaded as a module then after the user click the green square in the "Last 5 results" box there's an extra result. The first time is the proper one (time between green square appears and user click) and the second time is the time which gone from moment when page loaded.

I don't have any idea why that second time appears and I don't know why it appears sometimes not every drawing.

This is the link to the version using "requirejs" library:
http://doomini2.linuxpl.info/test/

I also tried to use "Event delegation", but it doesn't count the time from last "start" click but always from the first click after the page loaded.

This is the link to the version using "event delegation":
http://doomini2.linuxpl.info/test2/

Why do the last two version not work?
What causes the extra result?

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on Chrome 44, all 3 work the same for me. If you solved your problem you should answer it and mark your answer correct, or delete the question. If you didn't solve your problem, tell us what browser you're using?

Comment: I'm using firefox 40.0.2 and chrome 31.0.1650.59 and on both problem is the same.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the broken state? I'm afraid I still can't replicate it

Comment: I see the problem with Event Delegation now. Still not seeing the problem with requirejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your event delegation problem, this line needs to be moved:

```
 var start_time = Date.now();
```

The variable should be declared at the top level, so that both the button click function and "mix" function have access to it. Then you need to run `start_time = Date.now();` when the green box appears so the time is correct.

Comment: Hi. Now is working with "event delegation". Can you tell me why it didn't work with "event delegation" but was working with normal "addEventListener?". There is still problem with "requires", even when I moved that line. Problem not come out every time. Try click start button 20 times and keep eyes on "last 5 results". Finally you will get double the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, about either of those problems. I'm sorry!

Comment: Np. Thank you. Regards